# Number of points a one hidden layer neural-network can interpolate

Tags: neural-networks, approximation, interpolation

We am trying to understand the number of points that a neural network of a particular size can interpolate.  I think this may be isomorphic to its degree of freedom?  We are not interested in whether particular optimization methods would reach them, just if there is a theoretical bound.

To be precise: take a "neural network" with one hidden layer

$$
f(x) \equiv W_2 \cdot \sigma(W_1 \cdot x + b_1) + b_2
$$
Where,

- $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
- $\sigma(\cdot) = max(0, \cdot)$ element-wise (i.e.ReLU)
- $W_1 \in \mathbb{R^N}$
- $b_1 \in \mathbb{R^N}$
- $W_2 \in \mathbb{R^N}$
- $b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
- $\theta \in \{b_1, W_1, b_2, W_2\} \in \mathbb{R}^{3N+1}$

Note for a given $N$ there are $3N+1$ parameters.

**Question:** For a fixed $N$, what is the maximum number of points in $\mathbb{R}$ where there is always a $\theta$ which can interpolate them?  For other functional forms like orthogonal polynomials, the number of points is always the number of parameters, but isn't it lower than $3N+1$ due to the collinearity of the bias?

Comment: This is two layer (one-hidden layer nn), and $W_1$ is $N\times N$. For interpolation, f(x) should be equal to y for each x, y pair. For one layer NN, this boils down to solving the linear equation $WX+b\mathbf{1}=Y$, which certainly has its limits. For the two layer case, I believe there is still limit, but not sure if it's provable.

Comment: Oops sorry, yes meant one hidden layer. So there may not be a closed form solution in the above case?

Comment: Your notation says there are $N$ parameters in $W_1$, so are we only considering the where each $x$ is scalar?

Comment: yes, Sorry, I thought the $f : R \to R$ made that unambiguous?  Do you think I should add in $x \n R$ to make it even clearer?

Comment: Oh, I see that now. I missed it the first time. Basically, we can choose $N,W_1, b_1$ such that $\sigma(W_1 x + b_1)$ is a basis. Then we know that $W_2, b_2$ are just estimated from a regression. Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: THanks @Sycorax  I fear I might need more help since I am not thinking of this in terms of regressions/etc.  Someone separateley pointed out this reference though: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/hash/dbea3d0e2a17c170c412c74273778159-Abstract.html   but I don't see the exact formula.  Seems like "memoriziation" is the right machine-learning-y term though.

Comment: > Then we know that W2,b2 are just estimated from a regression.
So that means that it can fit `N+1` points if I think I see what you are getting at?

Comment: Yes. If you have $N+1$ linear equations and $N+1$ unknowns, you need the equations to be *distinct* and *consistent* to have a unique solution. We know this solution must interpolate (because the unknowns solve the linear system exactly).

Comment: Great if you post that in the answer I will accept it!